# Tcl with registry package fail with multi_sz value and empty strings

Tags: registry, tcl

Help me please to find the way to work from Tcl with Windows registry MULTI_SZ values and empty strings. If I try to get such values from registry then Tcl  cut result after first empty line.

For example, I have following value in reg key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations :

```
\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\tobedeleted\repDD55.tmp

\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Maintenance Service\maintenanceservice_tmp.exe

\??\C:\Config.Msi\a219072.rbf

\??\C:\Config.Msi\a219073.rbf

\??\C:\Config.Msi\a21907a.rbf
```

But when I use Tcl then got:

```
% registry get "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager" PendingFileRenameOperations
{\??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\tobedeleted\repDD55.tmp}
() 7 %
```

I try to use test case for this:

```
() 9 % registry set "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager" TEST [list foo bar baz bla] multi_sz
() 10 % registry get "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager" TEST
foo bar baz bla
() 11 % registry set "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager" TEST [list foo bar "" baz bla] multi_sz
() 12 % registry get "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager" TEST
foo bar
() 13 %
```

May be there is way to get multi_sz value as sz and then split it by null's? 
I have following environment:

```
% set tcl_patchLevel
8.6.5
package require registry
1.3.1
```